# inverse of the function $f(r,\theta) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

inverse of the function $f(r,\theta) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$

set $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$ then we have $ x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ so $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Now $y/x = \tan \theta$ so $ \arctan(y/x) = \theta$ for $x\not=0$. If $x=0$ we have $\theta = \text{arccot}(x/y)$ for the inverse.

In the solutions they have: in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ with $x_0 < 0$ we have $\theta = \arctan(y/x) + \pi$ and $\arctan(y/x) = \theta$ for $x_0 > 0$, and similarly for $y_0 >0 $and $<0$ - my question is, where did the $+\pi$ come from, and why do we distinguish if $x,y>0$ or $<0$?

Comment: Maybe they want to return the appropriate quadrant of the computed angle, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: The diagrams here might help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940102/why-is-that-for-any-trigonometric-function-f-f2-pi-theta-f-theta-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given function $f$ maps a pair of polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ to Cartesian coordinates $(r \cos\theta, r \sin \theta)$.

[image: poolar coordinates]

You can fiddle with it [here](http://ggbtu.be/m3196583).

The arcus tangens function will return a value from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, which covers only a total angle of $\pi$, not $2 \pi$. That is why they feature the case distinction.

$x > 0$ is for the right side half circle:

$x < 0$ for the left side half circle.

For $x = 0$ $\theta$ should be either $\pi/2$ $(y > 0)$ or $-\pi/2$ $(y< 0)$.

For $(x,y) = (0,0)$ there is no unique inverse.

Comment: and why do we want $2\pi$ instead of just $\pi$?

Comment: $\theta$ will cover a total angle of $2\pi$ for a full circle.

Comment: Could you explain why it's $+\pi$ on the rhs of the circle? and $-\pi$ on the lhs?

Comment: The angle $\theta$ is between the positive $x$-axis and the line segment between origin $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$. It grows counter-clockwise. For $x < 0$, on the left half of the plane, it would range from $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$. The negative angle means we go clockwise. An angle of $3\pi/2$ is the same as $-\pi/2$. So for the definition, on the left side the value goes from $-\pi/2 + \pi = \pi/2$ to $\pi/2 + \pi = 3\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let a point $(x_0,y_0)\ne(0,0)$ be given, and denote by $H$ the half plane $x_0x+y_0y>0$. Then one has
$$\theta=\theta_0+\arctan{x_0y-y_0x\over x_0x+y_0y}\qquad\bigl((x,y)\in H\bigr)\ ,$$
where $\theta_0$ is a polar angle of $(x_0,y_0)$.